# Problem with vector inside a class

Tags: arrays, vector

I have this code inside a class:

```
void SendStones()
{
    int currenthole = hole;
    int lastplace = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<stns.size();i++)
    {
        while(1)
        {//Calculate new currenthole
            if(currenthole == 13) { currenthole = 7; break;}
            if(currenthole == 14) { currenthole = 6; break;}
            if((currenthole<=12 && currenthole > 7) || (currenthole<=6 && currenthole > 1)) { currenthole--; break;}
        }
        lastplace = stns.size()-1;
        hole[currenthole]->ReciveStone(stns[lastplace]);//PROBLEM
        stns.pop_back();
    }
}

vector<Stones*> stns;
```

so it makes this error:
invalid types `int[int]' for array subscript

what's the problem?i don't understand.
Thanks.

Comment: Please format your code as code (`code`) or click on the 101010 after selecting code) for readability. Also, what language?

Comment: Reduce your code to the smallest snippet that will clearly reproduce the problem with the minimum number of dependencies on your project.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like hole is a simple int, and you're trying to subscript it.  Is that what you mean to do?  Where is hole declared?

Answer (score 0):

Hole is a really big class,
SendStones is a function member in the class.
I won't send the whole file but i can say that 
hole[currenthole] is a Hole *hole[14];
It's a big program and project so i sent the related code needed.

Here's the code of the ReciveStones function:

void ReciveStone(Stone *rcvstone)
             {
                  stns.push_back(rcvstone);
             }

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you said in your answer, hole is a pointer to *n* Hole objects.  That means your code isn't doing what you think it's doing.

```
int currenthole = hole;
```

This is storing an address value pointing to the first object in your array collection, which means that this code

```
if(currenthole == 13) { currenthole = 7; break;}
            if(currenthole == 14) { currenthole = 6; break;}
            if((currenthole<=12 && currenthole > 7) || (currenthole<=6 && currenthole > 1)) { currenthole--; break;}
```

is probably nonsense.

It doesn't explain why you're getting the *"invalid types `int[int]' for array subscript"* error.  Are you sure that there's not a second declaration of type *int* named *hole*?

--Actually, re-reading what you wrote, I'm even more certain you're not doing what you think you're doing.  SendStones is a member of the class Hole, correct?  Check that your Hole class doesn't have a hole member variable inside it.  That is probably the problem, since it will be found before any global variable called hole (if I remember my scoping rules correctly).